# Convertion from File Object to FileItem Object

Tags: java, apache-commons

I would like to **transform** this entire **File (java.io.File)** to **FileItem (org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem)**

Can any one provide the code snip for this.

Help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From FileItem's [javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html):

> This class represents a file or form item that was received within a multipart/form-data POST request

From File's [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

They both denote *completely different concepts*. There's no guarantee that a FileItem has an equivalent on disk (which could be pointed to as a java.io.File)

This makes me think that this is a [x-y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) and you should rephrase your question with the underlying problem.

Comment: is there any alternative to convert the file to FileItem?

Comment: it depends on what you actually are trying to achieve: Are you dealing with uploaded data, and want to pass it into an API function that requires a `java.io.File`? Or do you have a `java.io.File` and want to pass it into an API that requires an `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem`? That's what the xy-problem points to: You have chosen a solution, and are searching for a way to do what you've picked. But there's a good chance that your underlying problem requires a different solution to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```
    File file = new File("/etc/path/file");
    InputStream in = fileItem.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(in, out);
```

Don't forget to close streams.

Comment: I want to hold entire file ( Java.io.file object ) in FileItem.

Comment: InputStream in = fileItem.getInputStream();  -- Getting Compilation Error. fileitem